# Determining if a graph is hamiltonian?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I get that a  graph is called hamiltonian if it has a hamiltonian cycle but if I visit all the vertices of the graph once without using all the edges is it still called hamiltonian?

Comment: yes because a hamiltonian cycle, by definition, doesn't have to use all of the edges https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path

Comment: If you have a path that uses all the edges once each then the graph is Eulerian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hamiltonian graphs have a circuit that includes all the vertices. Eulerian graphs have a circuit that includes all the edges.

It's not difficult to have a graph that is Hamiltonian but not Eulerian: for example, a cycle graph with an extra edge (looking like $\theta$). Similarly a graph can be Eulerian but not Hamiltonian, for example. two cycles that share one point (looking like $8$).